# 600W power supply + Asus P7H55-M PRO: power light flash and turned off

Tags: motherboard, power-supply

I have an old Asus P7H55-M Pro motherboard: http://www.asus.com/Motherboards/Intel_Socket_1156/P7H55M_PRO/ and recently I bought a new 600W power supply (Coolmaster brand) but after I put all pieces together and turned on the power, the front panel blue light turned on but then quickly turned off and if I press the power button again, nothing happens unless I plug the computer out of the power source and plug it back in and then everything repeats.

I am just wondering what is the likely cause of the problem so that I can troubleshoot accordingly? Thanks!

Comment: Err, try the old power supply and see if that works. Also, does the light just blink once or what?

Comment: What pieces do you have connected? You should test with just the motherboard, CPU, RAM, and power supply.

Comment: @ekaj: the old power supply is broken and short-circuited the moment it was plugged in (even without PC powered on), that's what I changed the power supply.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Good point, I connected to too many pieces, I will give it a shot again today. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Don't know your level of 'computer building skills'. So, start with ...

1) Is the MB properly installed with stand-offs (ie - no metal touching / short-circuits)? 
2) Check the CPU and make sure no pins are bent and CPU is properly installed.
3) Remove and re-seat RAM or use 'known good' RAM.

Comment: Ha, 4 years ago, forgot to answer in the end, it was really because I didn't push the RAM stick down hard enough!